# Tensorflow Anomaly Detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, anomaly-detection

I was asked to create a machine algorithm using tensorflow and python that could detect anomalies by creating a range of 'normal' values. I have two perameters, a large array of floats around 1.5 and timestamps. I have not seen similar threads using tensorflow in a basic sense, and since I am new to technology I am looking to make a more basic machine. However, I would like to have it be unsupervised, meaning that I do not specify what an anomaly is, but rather a large amount of past data does. Thank you, I am running python 3.5 and tensorflow 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply normalize the values and feed it to the tensorflow autoencoder model.

So, autoencoders are deep neural networks used to reproduce the input at the output layer i.e. the number of neurons in the output layer is exactly the same as the number of neurons in the input layer. Consider the image below

[image]

The autoencoders work in a similar way. The encoder part of the architecture breaks down the input data to a compressed version ensuring that important data is not lost but the overall size of the data is reduced significantly. This concept is called Dimensionality Reduction.

Check this repo for code : [Autoencoder in tensorflow](https://github.com/Tensorflow-India/Tensorflow_Anomaly-Detection/blob/master/Tensorflow_autoencoder.py)